# Define a pattern for all properties of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Product interface defined in my application like so:

```
export interface Product {
  // other properties here
  datesForComparison?: {};
}
```

Basically I would expect `datesForComparison` is structured like this

```
{
  "2020-01-01": {
    price: 10,
    unitPrice: 5,
    percent: 5
  },
  "2020-01-02": {
    price: 4,
    unitPrice: 2,
    percent: -1
  },
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to define such repeating pattern of property in Typescript?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for an [Index Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
export interface Product {
  datesForComparison?: {
    [date: string]: {
      price: number;
      unitPrice: number;
      percent: number;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, I thought ```[date: string]: {}``` defines one property only. But in fact it actually defines a pattern for many properties?